# NDSolve for the system of 2 PDE's with terminal conditions

Tags: differential-equations

Trying to use NDsolve to find a numerical solution. However, it just returns the equations. I a newbie here, so help will be appreciated.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
tmax = 100

pdeV1 = D[V1[t, z1, z2], t] +
   (1/2 + 1/2*z2^2)*(D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1])^2*exp (r*t)*
    exp (lambda*(z1 + z2)) + (1 + z1^2)*D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1]*
    D[V2[t, z1, z2], z1]*exp (r*t)*exp (lambda*(z1 + z2)) +
   (D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2] + D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2]*z1^2)*
    exp (r*t)*(exp (lambda*z1) - 1) == 0


pdeV2 = D[V2[t, z1, z2], t] +
   (1/2 + 1/2*z2^2)*(D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2])^2*exp (r*t)*
    exp (lambda*(z1 + z2)) + (1 + z2^2)*D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2]*
    D[V1[t, z1, z2], z2]*exp (r*t)*exp (lambda*(z1 + z2)) +
   (D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1] + D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1]*z2^2)*
    exp (r*t)*(exp (lambda*z2) - 1) == 0


With[{r = 1, lambda = 1, P = 100}, 
 solution = NDsolveValue[{pdeV1, pdeV2,

V1[tmax, z1, z2] == P*exp (-lambda*z1) - P*exp (-lambda*(z1 + z2)),

V2[tmax, z1, z2] == P*exp (-lambda*z1) - P*exp (-lambda*(z1 + z2))

},



{V1, V2}, {t, 0, tmax}, {z1, 0, 100}, {z2, 0, 100}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t}]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for $exp()$ is `Exp[]` not `exp()` and `NDSolve` not `NDsolve`.
Furthermore, you have not enough boundary conditions, so `NDSolve` add artificial ones.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
tmax = 100; r = 1; lambda = 1; P = 100;

pdeV1 = D[V1[t, z1, z2], 
     t] + (1/2 + 1/2*z2^2)*(D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1])^2*Exp [r*t]*
     Exp [lambda*(z1 + z2)] + (1 + z1^2)*D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1]*
     D[V2[t, z1, z2], z1]*Exp[(r*t)]*
     Exp[ (lambda*(z1 + z2))] + (D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2] + 
       D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2]*z1^2)*Exp[(r*t)]*(Exp[lambda*z1] - 1) == 0;


pdeV2 = D[V2[t, z1, z2], 
     t] + (1/2 + 1/2*z2^2)*(D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2])^2*Exp[(r*t)]*
     Exp[(lambda*(z1 + z2))] + (1 + z2^2)*D[V2[t, z1, z2], z2]*
     D[V1[t, z1, z2], z2]*Exp [(r*t)]*
     Exp [(lambda*(z1 + z2))] + (D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1] + 
       D[V1[t, z1, z2], z1]*z2^2)*
     Exp [(r*t)]*(Exp[(lambda*z2)] - 1) == 0;

sol = NDSolve[{pdeV1, pdeV2, 
   V1[tmax, z1, z2] == 
    P*Exp[(-lambda*z1)] - P*Exp[(-lambda*(z1 + z2))], 
   V2[tmax, z1, z2] == 
    P*Exp [(-lambda*z1)] - P*Exp[(-lambda*(z1 + z2))]}, {V1, V2}, {t, 
   0, tmax}, {z1, 0, 100}, {z2, 0, 100}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 5*15 + 1, "MaxPoints" -> 5*15 + 1, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> Automatic}}]

Show[Plot3D[V1[tmax, z1, z2] /. sol, {z1, 0, 100}, {z2, 0, 100}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot3D[V2[tmax, z1, z2] /. sol, {z1, 0, 100}, {z2, 0, 100}, 
  PlotStyle -> Purple]]
```

Comment: the new problem arised: